# Talking to supervisord over xmlrpc

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, supervisord

I'm trying to talk to `supervisor` over xmlrpc. Based on [`supervisorctl`](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/supervisorctl.py) (especially [this line](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/options.py#L1512)), I have the following, which seems like it should work, and indeed it works, in so far as it connects enough to receive an error from the server:

```
#socketpath is the full path to the socket, which exists
# None and None are the default username and password in the supervisorctl options
In [12]: proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1', transport=supervisor.xmlrpc.SupervisorTransport(None, None, serverurl='unix://'+socketpath))

In [13]: proxy.supervisor.getState()
```

Resulting in this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/<ipython-input-13-646258924bc2> in <module>()
----> 1 proxy.supervisor.getState()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1222         return _Method(self.__send, "%s.%s" % (self.__name, name))
   1223     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1224         return self.__send(self.__name, args)
   1225
   1226 ##


/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.pyc in __request(self, methodname, params)
   1576             self.__handler,
   1577             request,
-> 1578             verbose=self.__verbose
   1579             )
   1580

/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.pyc in request(self, host, handler, request_body, verbose)
    469                                           r.status,
    470                                           r.reason,
--> 471                                           '' )
    472         data = r.read()
    473         p, u = self.getparser()

ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for 127.0.0.1/RPC2: 401 Unauthorized>
```

This is the `unix_http_server` section of `supervisord.conf`:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
;chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))
```

So, there should be no authentication problems.

It seems like my code is in all material respects identical to the equivalent code from `supervisorctl`, but `supervisorctl` actually works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks substantially correct.  I'm running Supervisor 3.0 with Python 2.7, and given the following:

```
import supervisor.xmlrpc
import xmlrpclib

p = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1',
        transport=supervisor.xmlrpc.SupervisorTransport(
            None, None,
            'unix:///home/lars/lib/supervisor/tmp/supervisor.sock'))

print p.supervisor.getState()
```

I get:

```
{'statename': 'RUNNING', 'statecode': 1}
```

Are you certain that your running Supervisor instance is using the configuration file you think it is?  What if you run `supervisord` in debug mode, do you see the connection?

Comment: The socket only showed up on the filesystem after I added the `unix_http_server` section to that file, so yeah, I'm fairly sure. I'll fiddle with debug mode.

Comment: The connection doesn't show up in debug mode. I'm using django-supervisor, through which I am able to run supervisorctl, whose connections also don't show up. Not sure what's up with that. I'm fairly certain that that's using the socket, because when I added the socket to the config without restarting supervisor, it wouldn't connect.

Comment: OK, for some reason it works if I explicitly set a username and password. I guess there's some kind of unhelpful magic being performed by django-supervisor behind the scenes. I also have a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729159/use-python-xmlrpclib-with-unix-domain-sockets if you care to answer it, I'll accept that also. If not, I'll add my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the ServerProxy from xmlrpclib, I use the Server class instead and I don't have to define any transports or paths to sockets. Not sure if your purposes require that, but here's a thin client I use fairly frequently. It's pretty much straight out of the docs.

```
python -c "import xmlrpclib;\
supervisor_client = xmlrpclib.Server('http://localhost:9001/RPC2');\
print( supervisor_client.supervisor.stopProcess(<some_proc_name>) )"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue; the problem was simple; `supervisord` was not running!

First:

```
supervisord
```

And then:

```
supervisorctl start all
```

**Done!** :)

> If you've set nodaemon to true, you must keep the process runing in another tab of your terminal.