# use xmlrpc with python 3 for communicate via domain socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-rpc, unix-socket

I want to write  xmlrpc server on python 3 that communicate
with clients via unix domain sockets.

I found this one [Use Python xmlrpclib with unix domain sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729159/use-python-xmlrpclib-with-unix-domain-sockets)

But the answer not working for python3.

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html#module-xmlrpc.server) `SimpleXMLRPCServer`
not accept `transport` argument, and because of `SimpleXMLRPCServer` based on `socketserver.TCPServer`
it is impossible to use `xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCServer` for unix domain sockets? Am I right?

What the most simple way to implement xmlrpc via unix domain sockets for python3?

```
wc -l /usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/server.py
986 /usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/server.py
```

It looks too expensive for me to reimplement it for domain sockets.